# Order by alias in mysql contained in if query

Tags: mysql, alias

I am using a query to select price from price column without dollar and then order by that alias after if statement. But order by that alias name is not working.

Query which I am using is

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  IF( SUBSTRING( price , '1', '1' ) = '$', 
      round( replace( price , '$', '' ) ) ,
      price ) AS coupon 
FROM ccs_product 
WHERE (product_name LIKE '%JoyLot.com%' 
       OR website_name LIKE '%JoyLot.com%' 
       OR description LIKE '%JoyLot.com%')
ORDER BY coupon ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 10;
```

Comment: What error do you got? It should work fine since the `ORDER BY` clause is executed after the `SELECT` clause in MySQL.

Comment: Actually it doesn't produced the ordered result, it displays randomly

Comment: I never said it produces any error

Comment: @SahilAgarwal see below query it works... use   round(price)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this query its works use round(price)

```
   SELECT 
       *, 
         IF( SUBSTRING( price , '1', '1' ) = '$', 
              round( replace( price , '$', '' ) ) ,
              round(price) ) AS coupon 
          FROM ccs_product 
         WHERE (product_name LIKE '%JoyLot.com%' 
     OR website_name LIKE '%JoyLot.com%' 
     OR description LIKE '%JoyLot.com%')
        ORDER BY coupon ASC 
   LIMIT 0 , 10;
```

Comment: Thank you manish it really worked for me that was a great reply and sorry for the late response

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem using the alias to do the order by. Check this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfdc2/10) as proof